# update issue ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, oracle, runtime-error

im trying to update but this error is not being able to solve through many solutions i saw on similar errors 
im using oracle sql for database

Find the below detail

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

From the cx_Oracle manual section [Using Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html):

> A bind variable is a colon-prefixed identifier or numeral. For
>   example, there are two bind variables (dept_id and dept_name) in this
>   SQL statement:

```
sql = """insert into departments (department_id, department_name)
          values (:dept_id, :dept_name)"""
cursor.execute(sql, [280, "Facility"])
```

You are using '?', which are not supported by Oracle's SQL.